# Find and update fields inside an array

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create a better and simpler criteria for an update command. But I can't figure out how I can fetch all users which have any campaigns I search for:

```
"data" : "a name",    
"campaigns" : [     
          {     "id" : ObjectId("4ff3f07eacf4794426000154"),    "name" : "test" },
          {     "id" : ObjectId("4ff3f07eacf4794426000154"),    "name" : "fisk test2" }
    ]
```

What I want to do is to update "test" to maybe "OS 2012".

To do this, I thought of using something similar to this:

```
db.users.update({"campaigns.name": "test"}, {$set : {campaigns: {'test' : 'OS 2012'}}});
```

The problem with that update statement is that it will probably remove any other campaigns that the user have in it's array? I just want to update "test" to "test2" and the best way I can find right now is to first use $pull and then $addToSet.

Is there a better way? Can you show me an example?

Thanks for you advice and better wisdom.

Comment: Is there a collection `campaigns`? I though it was `users`.

Comment: What do you mean `db.users.find({"campaigns.name": "test"})` doesn't work? Works for me.

Comment: It works for me now too, I think I must have misspelled something. In reality the campaign.name wasn't "test" but a string with capital letter, space and so on. :)

Comment: Well, then remove that from the post and don't confuse other readers :)

Comment: I already did, also I accepted your answer now. Thanks yet again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn about [the $ positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator). This code works.

```
db.users.update({'campaigns.name': 'test'}, 
                {$set: {'campaigns.$.name': 'blah blah'}})
```

Comment: Damn, you're fast. Although, I solved it straight after and that's why I removed my comment. I solved it by doing like this instead: `{$set: {'campaigns': {id: ObjectId("123..."), name: 'blah blah'}}})`